# what is better to learn for pattern recognition?

Tags: c++, c

c or c++??

if i want to make a project on pattern recognition( artificial computing)
using c or c++
which one should i choose??

Comment: I don't think it really matters. Use whichever you feel more comfortable with.

Comment: I'd choose neither, and use a functional language instead. But go with what you are proficient with.

Comment: i have to choose one of them .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object Oriented Programming can probably be of some help if you start programming something complex. That is possible with C but will probably be easier using C++. That said there is a risk to get lost on the multitude of features of the language if you are just learning it, and it's probably less so with C. But it's not so hard to use only a subset of C++, so definitely C++.

The most important point is that you should first focus on the problem(s) to solve before focusing on the tools you are using.

Answer (score 2):

I would use something high level so you could learn about your own algorithms and not how to implement your algorithms. If you can write pattern recognition single handedly in C I applaud you. It is beyond my skill.

Perhaps Ruby or Python then implementing the computationally expensive parts in native C?

Comment: +1 if you use C, you're going to need to be pretty proficient at implementing basic algorithms. C++ is a better choice because it'll let you get more done faster. Python is an even better choice.

Comment: thanks.....but i can only go with one of the two...c or c++ according to course strructure or java ...but am not comfortable with java

Answer (score 1):

Since C++ is effectively a superset of C, there is no good reason not to use C++.

Comment: Except for the complexity and portability. C++ is a much more complex language than C, and C is easier to port to other platforms.

Comment: Conversely C is a subset of C++ and could be used with other C projects or C++ projects using extern "C".

Comment: that means i should choose c++ for my project??

Comment: but the complexity of c++ can take my project marks away

Comment: The "complexity" of C++ is there to allow you to implement your application using higher level concepts, so, all in all, it should help you to work more *easily* (well, if you know C++ `:)` ).

Comment: By superset, I mean that most C code will compile in a C++ compiler. You can also use the latest and greatest Boost libraries, or anything in between. It is up to you to choose whether to embrace the extra complexity

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the least of your worries. C is available on more platforms, C++ has more features.